# Rename Minecraft Advancements without removing them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to modify the minecraft advancements in a way that changes the title but doesn't modify anything else. Is there any way I can do this? I'm working with 1.16.5 currently.

Comment: Are you opposed to using a resource pack?

Comment: No, I am not. If that is the best way to go, can you lead me to a source that tells me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resource pack can rename everything by changing the [lang file](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_Pack#Language) for translations. If your resource pack (a normal zip file, or filesystem folder, that you put in the resource pack folder you find at Settings > Resource Packs > Open Resource Pack Folder) has a `assets/minecraft/lang/en_gb.json` file in it, you can change the English (Great Britain) language to say, for example:

```
{
    "advancements.nether.find_fortress.title": "Siege",
    "advancements.nether.find_fortress.description": "Break down the walls of the blazes' castle"
}
```

If you open your `.minecraft` folder (one above the Resource Pack folder), you can find a `assets/indexes` folder with `.json` files in it; each of these will describe mappings of names (names you can overwrite in your resource pack's own `assets` folder, like `minecraft/lang/en_gb.json`) to a SHA-1 sum of the contents of their entry in the default resource pack. You can then find the original file in `assets/objects` under the given SHA-1 sum—this will allow you to see what the language file originally had in it, so you know what to overwrite. Unlike other resource pack files, language files are combinative and not directly overwritten—you do not have to write the entries for things you don't intend to change.